# Where do I put code to modify a control in an Access report?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've written VBA code in Excel, but now I have to modify listbox in an Access report and I don't know where the code goes. Sorry so stupid. Is there an event like On_Report_Run or something? There must be a Reports collection somewhere, but I don't see any objects in the object explorer that have a name like the report. Does the code go in a module?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! There is a `Reports` collection that you can use in code to enumerate open reports. For a report to show up in the Project Explorer view in the VBA IDE, the report must have a class module bound to it. Check the `Has Module` property of the report. Code goes into event properties of the report, its sections and controls. Check the `Events` tab of the `Property Sheet` when the report is in design view.

Comment: thanks. I've inherited a report that uses a large denormalized data set with parents children and grandchildren, and in the parents band they want to put a listbox with the children. I need to see how access handles all that.

Comment: You can't put child reports in a listbox, but you can add a subgroup in the parent band to contain your sub-reports.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the report in design view
2. right click the upper left corner of the report
3. Select "build event" from the popup menu.
4. Choose "Code Builder" in the dialog that appears after choosing "build event"
5. Access will create a module for the form, and create an empty procedure declaration for the On_Open event. write whatever code you need to modify controls, labels, and so on in the On_Open event.

NOTE: My answer assumes that all the information you need to modify the report is known at the time you open the report. I personally use the OpenArgs argument of the OpenReport method to pass information into the On_Open method. If the On_Open event doesn't meet your needs, check the drop-down list in the VBA editor to see what other events are available in the report. Other events include On_Load, LostFocus, and several more.

I hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Note that OpenArgs is available anywhere in the report's code, not just in the Open event.

Comment: I did not intend to imply that the value of OpenArgs was not available outside of the On_Open event-handler.